# Facebook app error when leaving "native ios app" field blank

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook

I previously had a facebook app working great with my native IOS app.  I recently recreated the app to rename it for when we release to the app store.

When I select "Native IOS App" and enter the bundled Id but leave "iphone app store id" blank, I get this error:

"Error
You have enabled a Native iOS App integration for your app, but have not specified an iPhone App Store ID or iPad App Store ID"

It says this field is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Use 210849718975311, the iPhone App Store ID used by the sample application Hackbook found on Facebook's developer pages.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around go ahead and add any valid iTunes app ID, even if you do not have a live app in the iTunes store. Once your app goes through iTunes you can come back and change this setting. The other alternative is to come back and add your bundle ID and iTunes information when your app is live.

Comment: The real problem is that when call the`[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];` method it redirects to a blank facebook page with a cancel button at the top.  I noticed there is also an "advanced->app type" on the facebook app that's set to native.  Is that good enough or do I have to make it a native IOS app by your workaround above?

Comment: Set the advance>app type to "web". You can even skip entering the Native iOS App section for now as I mentioned in the workaround.